# Getting “wlan0: Association Request to driver failed” error when using Raspberry Pi 3b+ as client to perform fast handover using 802.11r

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, 802.11

I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi 3b+  as a client to perform fast handover ([802.11r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11r-2008)).

I am using [`wpa_supplicant-2.6`](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/) and I have also enabled 802.11r while I was building it from the source code.

It is said that Raspberry Pi 3b+ supports fast handover but in my case it is not entering into network.

Below is the detail of my `wpa_supplicant` config file:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
updaate_config=1
pmf=1
network={
                  ssid="iisc-FT"
                   psk="*******"
                   key_mgmt=FT-PSK
}
```

I am initializing my `wpa_supplicant` with this command:

```
/home/pi/Downloads/wpa_supplicant-2.6/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -dd  -Dnl80211 -c/home/pi/Downloads/wpa_supplicant-2.6/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant _template.conf.
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
wlan0: Association Request to driver failed
```